# Routing Traffic from OpenVPN Server -> Local Network -> OpenVPN Client

Tags: vpn, openvpn, nat, pfsense

So I have a PFsense box running on my home network. I set up PIA as the a VPN client using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ov-xddVpxhc) tutorial found here as well as a helpdesk [article](https://helpdesk.privateinternetaccess.com/guides/routers/pfsense-2-4-5-openvpn-setup) from PIA themselves. After getting that all setup I wanted to setup a VPN server on PFsense so I could securely access my home network from anywhere. I followed this guide from [Netgate](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/recipes/openvpn-ra.html) in order to setup my VPN server. So the issues comes along when I am VPN into my network... my traffic is no longer going through PIA as it exits. How can I accomplish this task? I know this is possible according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/l9l0oc/tunnel_openvpn_server_traffic_through_openvpn/) Reddit post I just don't know how to go about doing it.

So far I have tried to create NAT rules but since they are not in the reddit post I am not sure what I need. I was able how ever to change the default gateway to PIA.

Comment: The linked reddit thread has a few suggestions, did you try those out?

Comment: I did. I just did not know how to configure my NAT with the proper rules as the post does not list specific rules

Comment: Ok, that's a much better question to start with! Could you edit your question to indicate what steps you've tried from the reddit thread and where you get stuck?